# Turtle not responding to input

Tags: python, tetris, python-turtle

I'm attempting to create the game tetris using the turtle module in python but I'm running into some issues.

Previously I was having a problem where some of the blocks making up my square piece would move left to right, but not all of them. I realized that the problem was the script was receiving the player's input in the middle of the for loop updating the positions in the `update_pos()` function after some blocks had already moved.

My solution was to disable player input while the for loop that update the blocks was running by saying

```
scn.onkeypress(None, "a")
scn.onkeypress(None, "d")
```

But once I did this the blocks would no longer move left or right at all. All I could guess was happening was player input was never getting properly re-enabled but I'm not sure why.

```
import turtle
import time
import random

last_check = time.time()
spawn_pos = (-12.5, 345)
interval = 2.5
x_input, y_input = 0, 0
colors = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue"]

scn = turtle.Screen()
scn.setup(1280, 720)

brick = turtle.Turtle()
brick.penup()
brick.pencolor("black")
brick.speed(0)
brick.shape("square")
brick.shapesize(1.05, 1.05, 1.5)

def update_pos(current_shape):
    global x_input, y_input
    scn.onkeypress(None, "a")
    scn.onkeypress(None, "d")
    for a in range(4):
        current_shape[a][1].setpos((current_shape[a][1].xcor() + x_input), (current_shape[a][1].ycor() + y_input - 25))
    x_input, y_input = 0, 0
    scn.onkeypress(move_left, "a")
    scn.onkeypress(move_right, "d")


def spawn_square():
    shape = [[(0, 0)], [(25, 0)], [(25, -25)], [(0, -25)]]
    brick.fillcolor("yellow")
    brick.setpos(spawn_pos)
    move_bricks(shape)
    return(shape)

def move_bricks(shape):
    for i in range(4):
        brick.fillcolor(colors[i])
        shape[i].append(brick.clone())
        shape[i][1].setpos((shape[i][1].xcor() + shape[i][0][0]), (shape[i][1].ycor() + shape[i][0][1]))

def move_left():
    global x_input
    x_input -= 25

def move_right():
    global x_input
    x_input += 25

scn.onkeypress(move_left, "a")
scn.onkeypress(move_right, "d")
scn.listen()

current_shape = spawn_square()

while True:
    if time.time() - last_check > interval:
        last_check = time.time()
        if current_shape[3][1].ycor() <= -300:
            y_input = 600
        update_pos(current_shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues with your code:

- You don't update the drawing immediately based on user input, you wait for the vertical redraw.  So the user doesn't get feedback of the result of their actions.
- You were using a timer loop that potentially locked out events.  (For example, try closing your window, it delays until the next vertical redraw.)  I've changed this to use turtle's timer event instead so things work together better.

I've reworked your code below to run as I believe you intended:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SPAWN_POS = (-12.5, 370)
INTERVAL = 1000  # milliseconds
COLORS = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']

x_input, y_input = 0, 0

def update_pos(shape):
    global x_input, y_input

    for a in range(4):
        shape[a][1].setpos((shape[a][1].xcor() + x_input), (shape[a][1].ycor() + y_input))

    x_input, y_input = 0, 0

    screen.update()

def spawn_square():
    shape = [[(0, 0)], [(25, 0)], [(25, -25)], [(0, -25)]]
    move_bricks(shape)

    return shape

def move_bricks(shape):
    for i in range(4):
        brick.fillcolor(COLORS[i])
        shape[i].append(brick.clone())
        shape[i][1].setpos((shape[i][1].xcor() + shape[i][0][0]), (shape[i][1].ycor() + shape[i][0][1]))

    screen.update()

def move_left():
    global x_input

    x_input -= 25
    update_pos(current_shape)

def move_right():
    global x_input

    x_input += 25
    update_pos(current_shape)

def drop_bricks():
    global y_input

    screen.onkeypress(None, 'a')
    screen.onkeypress(None, 'd')

    if current_shape[3][1].ycor() <= -300:
        y_input = 600
    else:
        y_input -= 25

    update_pos(current_shape)

    screen.onkeypress(move_left, 'a')
    screen.onkeypress(move_right, 'd')

    screen.ontimer(drop_bricks, INTERVAL)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1280, 720)
screen.tracer(False)
screen.listen()

brick = Turtle()
brick.penup()
brick.shape('square')
brick.shapesize(1.05, 1.05, 1.5)
brick.setpos(SPAWN_POS)

current_shape = spawn_square()

drop_bricks()

screen.mainloop()
```